# Interpolate an object key from a string

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, interpolation

In Unity, I have two arrays, one of strings:

```
var options = new string[] { "north", "east", "south", "west" };
```

and another of JSON objects named `room`, which I've setup per the MULTIPLE DATA(ARRAY JSON) solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36239705/deserialization-of-json-using-minijson-in-unity-c-sharp/36244111#36244111). I won't list it here cos it's massive, but basically I can call `room[1].north` and get some text back successfully.

I want to add many more things to the options array, so I'm trying to write a foreach loop that will iterate over everything in the options array and perform the same methods on each, i.e.

```
foreach (string option in options) {
  GameObject optionObject = GameObject.Find (option);
  TextMesh optionTextMesh = optionObject.GetComponent<TextMesh> ();
  optionTextMesh.text = room[1].{some way to pass in "option" as the key};
}
```

Is it possible to interpolate a key on an object like this?

Comment: That depends entirely on the type of `room` and `room[1]`. Generally a JSON node class has a string indexer you can access to retrieve its members, so `room[1]["north"]`. Expect people to suggest reflection, but don't go that way.

Comment: @CodeCaster ah, that could indicate I've gone the wrong route with the `room` array. I've created a custom class, Room, and a JSON helper class that wraps all the objects in the array so I can access those values (I'm new to C# and Unity, AFAIK Unity doesn't play with arrays of JSON objects).